# Call the web SOAP Api that is HTTPS on android studio and getting 500 error

Tags: c#, android, .net, android-studio, soap

i am trying to call the SOAP api on android studio who has HTTPS protocol and i am getting error 500 any help from you guys will make my day i already waste too much time on this issue not getting any help from any where i do not know where i am doing wrong
name space is with = HTTP
please open the base link if some one can

```
https://183.87.134.37/DemoRitmanpayinapi/RitmanPay.svc?wsdl  // base URL to get data



  public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
public static final String URL = "https://183.87.134.37/DemoRitmanpayinapi/RitmanPay.svc?wsdl";
public static final String SOAP_ACTION = "Ser/IRitmanPay/GetIDType";
public static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetIDType";
```

this are name space and other cred

```
public class getTransferRate extends AsyncTask<String , Object , String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE , METHOD_NAME);
        soapObject.addProperty("PartnerCode" , "161333");
        soapObject.addProperty("UserName" , "WAMOBILEAPP");
        soapObject.addProperty("UserPassword" , "WAMOBILEAPP");
        soapObject.addProperty("CountryShortName" , "ind");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope sr = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        sr.dotNet = true;
        sr.bodyOut = soapObject;

        sr.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);


      // HttpsTransportSE se = new HttpsTransportSE(URL , 30000);

        HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL , 30000);

        try {

            transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION , sr);
            Log.e( "doInBackground: ", (String) sr.getResponse());
        }catch ( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Ex" , e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

can any one please help me to sort out my problem

Comment: Your code is using https which is secure and uses TLS for authentication. You are probably failing the authentication.  The TLS is sent before the HTTPS. So if you use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the results. You will see the TLS and if you see the https then the authentication passed. Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1  due to secure issues. Microsoft did a security push in June disabling TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers. Client s were still requesting TLS 1.0/1.1 and the client code needed to be changed. Check Sniffer to see if you are still using old TLS.

Comment: can you please guide me how can i access this server on android because i am new on SOAP

Comment: The issue need to be fixed where either the Client or Request is opened.  It is in the method :HttpTransportSE(URL , 30000);  the fix can either be made in the c# code or the operating system.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/transport-layer-security?tabs=windows